# How can I provide a validation error if some of the object properties are invalid?

Tags: javascript, validate.js

I wrote the following validation configuration:

```
    const presenceTrue = {
      presence: { allowEmpty: false },
    };

    const constraints = {
      "opportunity.name": presenceTrue,
      "opportunity.id": presenceTrue,
    };
```

I could not find a way to create a custom validator for the opportunity object value but instead I followed validate.js advice on how to validate nested properties within an object property.

My default property value for the `opportunity` field is `{ name: null, id: null }`, However when I execute `validate()` and opportunity is still `{ name: null, id: null }`, the return value is the following:

```
{
  "opportunity.id": "Opportunity id can't be blank",
  "opportunity.name": "Opportunity name can't be blank"
}
```

I would like the validation result to be either:

```
{
  "opportunity": "Opportunity can't be blank" (because either id or name properties are blank)
  "opportunity.id": "Opportunity id can't be blank",
  "opportunity.name": "Opportunity name can't be blank"
}
```

or:

```
{
  "opportunity": "Opportunity can't be blank"
}
```

Comment: Please click [edit], then the icon marked `[<>]` to make a snippet with a [mcve] with relevant HTML, CSS and frameworks/plugins from CDN